# how to open another listview using onitemclick of current listview?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I want my current listview to open a new listview when an item is pressed in current `ListView`.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import static android.R.attr.name;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_listview);

        HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
        nameAddresses.put("Chairman Seceretery", "7th floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Corporate Affairs Division", "6th floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Director(Technical) Secretariat", "5th Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Operations", "5th Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Emergency Control room", "5th Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Enterprise risk management", "5th Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Business Planning", "5th Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Director(Finance) Secretariat", "4rth Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Finance", "4rth Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("DIRECTOR (PERSONNEL) SECRETARIAT", "3rd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Personnel", "3rd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("ED(LAW)& PLO", "3rd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Business Planning", "3rd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Transformation monitoring office", "3rd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Vigilance", "2nd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Administration", "2nd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Parliament Cell", "2nd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Corporate Planning", "2nd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Coal Import Group", "2nd Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Director(P&SP) Secretariat", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Business Planning", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("C & IT", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Medical & Health Service", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Director(RM&L) Secretariat", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("CRMG", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("ICVL", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("O/o ED(Forest)", "1st Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Reception", "Ground Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("State Bank Of India", "Ground Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Library", "Ground Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Basement", "Ground Floor");
        nameAddresses.put("Administration-Kaushambi ", "Ground Floor");
        Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(nameAddresses);


        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});


        Iterator it = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultsMap);
        }
        resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Adminstrative.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }





}

Mainxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/results_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**2nd Activity:**

```
package com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Adminstrative extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adminstrative);
        ListView resultsListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.administrative);
        HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses1 = new HashMap<>();
        nameAddresses1.put("xyz", "7th floor");

        Map<String, String> treeMap1 = new TreeMap<String, String>(nameAddresses1);


        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems1 = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems1, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});


        Iterator it = treeMap1.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultsMap1 = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultsMap1.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultsMap1.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems1.add(resultsMap1);
        }
        resultsListView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
}

**administrative.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1.Adminstrative">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/adminstrative"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Every time I use to run the application.It crashes.What could be the issue??can anyone help me out.I have called 2nd activity using current activity's `onClickItem` method but it's not working

Comment: @yatin deokar can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: add your crash log

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1/com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1.MainActivity}: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**                                                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend activity with `ListActivity` , so your id should be `android:id="@android:id/list"` for ListView with **@android:**.

If you want custom list view just use `extends AppCompatActivity` for your activity then you can use same id as above. i hope this will help you.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.brandonmain.listviewexample1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```